# Copying relational data with non-trivial relationships

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, copy, relational-database

Say we have these tables:

```
                  +-------------------------+
                  | Orphanage               |
                  |-------------------------|
                  | ID                      |
                  |                         |
                  +-------------------------+


      +-------------------------+    +-------------------------+
      | Room                    |    | Orphan                  |
      |-------------------------|    |-------------------------|
      | ID                      |    | ID                      |
      | Orphanage ID            |    | Orphanage ID            |
      |                         |    |                         |
      +-------------------------+    +-------------------------+


                     +-------------------------+
                     | Room Movement           |
                     |-------------------------|
                     | ID                      |
                     | Orphan ID               |
                     | From Room ID            |
                     | To Room ID              |
                     |                         |
                     +-------------------------+
```

`Room Movement` gets a new entry when an Orphan is moved from one room to another.

Now say I wanted to copy an entire `Orphanage`, complete with all the related entities.  `Room` and `Orphan` are simple enough to copy - save the new Orphanage to create the ID, and pass it to clones of the Room and Orphan - but entries in `Room Movement` are slightly more complicated.  I would have to maintain a map of old to new IDs for both Orphans and Rooms and do a lookup for each insert.  This is simple in this contrived example, but in reality we have a lot of these kinds of relationships under `Orphanage`, and nested levels of these FK relationships.

Two questions: is this something the ORM should handle?  This is a problem not unique to our application, and it seems like with properly configured foreign keys and some sort of "clone strategy" system the ORM should do the heavy lifting and do things in the right order.

If not, is there somewhere where I can read up on this problem and see how other people solved it without creating a big mess of code?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are failing to understand the difference between
surrogate keys and natural keys. Your ID columns are *surrogate keys*,
the reason they are present in your model is because they make certain
tasks easier for the ORM and the RDBMS. Your model should be
consistent even if you omit them.

Clearly, your model is not because if you do, then `Orphanage` has no
attributes, `Room` and `Orphan` only references to the orphanage they
are situated in and so on.

To fix that problem you need to add *natural keys* to your model. A
natural key (NK) is a combination of one or more columns that are
unique in the table. For `Orphanage`, I would add a column `name` and the
NK would be the name of the orphanage (it's a reasonable
simplification that no two orphanages have the same name, but in the
real world that assumption doesn't hold):

```
Orphanage
---------
name
NK: (name)
```

For `Room`, we can add a column `room_nr` and have that be the NK. But
it's not enough because clearly two orphanages can have a room with
the same `room_nr`, so the combination of the `orphanage_id` and
`room_nr` should be the NK:

```
Room
----
orphanage_id
room_nr
NK: (orphanage_id, room_nr)
```

Same reasoning to figure out what the NK for a `Kid` is (I like that
table name better because the words "orphan" and "orphanage" are too
similar). We assume that the name is unique per orphanage. So there
can be no two "Joe" in the same orphanage:

```
Kid
---
orphanage_id
name
NK: (orphanage_id, name)
```

For `RoomMovement`:

```
RoomMovement
------------
kid_id
from_room_Id
to_room_id
NK: (kid_id, from_room_id, to_room_id)
```

Note that this table is kind of incorrect. You can't represent a kid
being moved from room A to B to A and then back to B again. Such
design errors happens all the time when you don't spend time thinking
about the model's natural keys. But for the problem of cloning the
orphanage, it's inconsequential.

With all the natural keys defined the next step becomes very easy. Say
the old orphanage is named "St. James" and you want to clone it into
"St. Clara":

```
-- make a new orphanage
insert into Orphanage values ('St. Clara');

-- copy all the rooms
insert into Room(room_nr, orphanage_id)
select
    r.room_nr,
    (select id from Orphanage where name = 'St. Clara')
from
    Room r
    join Orphanage o on r.orphanage_id = o.id
where
    o.name = 'St. James'

-- copy all the kids in almost the same way.
insert into Kid(name, orphanage_id)
select
    k.name,
    (select id from Orphanage where name = 'St. Clara')
from
    Kid k
    join Orphanage o on k.orphanage_id = o.id
where
    o.name = 'St. James'

-- copy all the room movements
insert into RoomMovement (from_room_id, to_room_id, kid_id)
select
    (select id from Room
     where room_nr = r_from.room_nr and orphanage_id = o_to.id),
    (select id from Room
     where room_nr = r_to.room_nr and orphanage_id = o_to.id),
    (select id from Kid
     where name = k.name and orphanage_id = o_to.id)
from
    RoomMovement rm
    join Room r_from on rm.from_room_id = r_from.id
    join Room r_to on rm.to_room_id = r_to.id
    join Kid k on rm.kid_id = k.id
    join Orphanage o_from on o_from.id = k.orphanage_id
    join Orphanage o_to on o_to.name = 'St. Clara'
where
    o_from.name = 'St. James';
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful and informative post.  We toyed with the idea of using natural keys here (in conjunction with the surrogates) but decided against it because (1) we are adding additional columns simply to make duplication easier and (2) we have never seen this implemented, and are unsure of the implications with our application ORM layer.  We are going to investigate using the object graph in the ORM to duplicate the data and have the graph work out the insertion order and FK relationships for us.  Cheers.

Comment: Natural keys are enforced using unique-constraints in your rdbms. But even if they aren't enforced, there must exist at least one for each table otherwise your data model falls apart. That you think you can "decide against them" sounds to me like you miss something fundamental about data modelling and that your difficulties in cloning your data is just one symptom of it.

Comment: We are using natural keys for constraining the data, but we would rather keep this copying logic in our application space if we can, and not use them to copy entities in SQL.  My question is whether the ORM layer should handle this, or whether we need to implement our own solution in code and handle the dependency graph ourselves.

Comment: @sennett & BjörnLindqvist Sometimes application-determined values/names/identifiers become visible. Whether such a value "is" natural and/or surrogate depends on how you define those words. Regardless, they are just as user-visible as "Tuesday" or "seventeen" or "Bjorn". It's just that the correspondence with named entity was established *after* the system started. (In the case of "Bjorn", the "Lindqvist family" system.) It is *not* necessary that any particular associated values be in the database. *Every* "natural" key column value was such a "natural surrogate" when introduced.

Comment: @sennet: No the ORM won't do it for you. An entity in a database can be generalized as a node in an arbitrary graph and having the ORM trying to figure out what the appropriate deepcopy semantics for it is, is asking for too much. You have to implement what cloning an orphanage means yourself, either using the sql code i wrote or by translating it into your ORM:s equivalent. I don't think a general function for copying by traversing all object dependencies would be practical but im not sure.

Answer (score 0):

In general one cannot build a clone according to any particular order of constraints. (Application relationships are represeted by *tables*; FKs although called "relationships" are *constraints*.) What matters to reconstructing a user-visible application state is a valid initial state and some equivalent possible (let alone the actual) sequence of events/transitions from it to the current state. (It might not even be possible to reconstruct those given the data that one otherwise wants in the database.)

However what *matters* is not that a clone be built up that way but simply that it be set to some user-visible equivalent application state--by definition, one that could have arisen by transitions. That means, copy the database state then enable constraints.

A system is a finite state machine: it has an initial state then goes through transitions to others. There's no reason that every legal state be reachable by legal transitions from some sort of particular "all relations empty" state.

If some non-application-user-visible ids are arbitrary in the pre-cloned value then they are arbitrary in the cloned system. So you can just copy the state.

But if those ids are not totally arbitrary (eg they could be clone-implementation-specific OIDs) that must be created by legal transitions (I repeat, not per constraints/FKs but transitions) then the system must have some known clone- and surrogate- independent initial database state and each current database state must determine some legal (it doesn't have to reconstruct the actual) sequence of transitions suitable for cloning. That might indeed be entirely represented by an all-tables-empty intial state and/or by the FK graph. (Despite other constraints that might have to be satisfied after each transition.)

So an ORM *could* offer help with the "all-tables-empty intial state and by the FK graph" version of that. But *should* it? It is naive to expect that your database state can be reconstructed from an empty database in order of FK constraints tuple by tuple and never violating other constraints. Constraints are not even necessarily acyclic.

Moreover, *non-arbitrary application-invisible surrogates are contrary to modeling relationally*. You should have a version of the database that is implementation-independent. In which case you can just initialize a clone to an entire database state. You might have a related database schema that is implementation-specific because you want to leverage relational technology for your implementation. But to generate valid OID values expect to have to *design* any clone-generating initial state and transitions into your database.

I am just riffing on fundamentals of the relational model and of software design. I can't refer you to a particular supporting product or design reference. In particular ORMs generally do not understand the relational model so cannot be expected to support what you want to do using the right abstractions.  I hope this message contributes to your sufficiently and explicity designing your system to be "clonable" in its particular sense.